# major issues with cURLpp and Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, http, libcurl, curlpp

I am attempting to use cURLpp as an avenue for retrieving data from a weather website for a final project in my C++ class. I am using Eclipse as an IDE and MinGW as my compiler. All I want to be able to do is send a GET request to the weather API and retrieve the data that is returned. I have done some extensive research, and it appeared that cURLpp was the way to go.

I have spent hours trying to get it configured in Eclipse and I'm still getting errors. I downloaded both libcURL and cURLpp. I am not sure if the versions I downloaded are correct though. The names of the files I downloaded are:

"curlpp-0.7.3.tar.gz" and "curl-7.22.0-devel-mingw32.zip"

Once I downloaded these two files, I extracted them both to an arbitrary directory. In eclipse, I added to my Includes path:

"C:\FinalProgrammingProjectData\cURL\curlpp-0.7.3.tar\curlpp-0.7.3\include"
"C:\FinalProgrammingProjectData\cURL\curl-7.22.0-devel-mingw32\curl-7.22.0-devel-mingw32\include"

I added to my Library Paths:
"C:\FinalProgrammingProjectData\cURL\curl-7.22.0-devel-mingw32\lib"

Under the libraries tab, I added the names of the individual files that are located inside:
"C:\FinalProgrammingProjectData\cURL\curl-7.22.0-devel-mingw32\lib"

When I try to build my project, I get alot of errors saying something along the lines of:

"undefined reference to"

Does anyone have any idea what my problem might be? I haven't written any of my own code. I've just been trying to compile the first example that is included with the cURLpp download. If anyone can offer any insight, I'd be most grateful. I have been wrestling with this for hours and haven't made much progress.

Thank You

P.S. Here is the build configuration with a list of the errors

Build of configuration Debug for project curlTest **

Internal Builder is used for build               **
g++ -LC:\FinalProgrammingProjectData\cURL\curl-7.22.0-devel-mingw32\lib -LC:\FinalProgrammingProjectData\cURL\curlpp-0.7.3.tar\curlpp-0.7.3\src -o curlTest.exe curlTest.o -lcurl -lidn.dll -lrtmp -lssh2 -lssh2dll -lssl -lssl32 -lz -lzdll -leay32 -lidn -lcurldll -lcrypto
curlTest.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\School\Fall 2011\EEL3834\Eclipse Projects\curlTest\Debug/../curlTest.cpp:32: undefined reference to`*imp***ZlsRSoRKN6curlpp11OptionTraitISsL10CURLoption10002EEE'
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\School\Fall 2011\EEL3834\Eclipse Projects\curlTest\Debug/../curlTest.cpp:37: undefined reference to `_imp___ZlsRSoRKN6curlpp11OptionTraitISsL10CURLoption10002EEE'
curlTest.o: In function`~OptionTrait':
C:/FinalProgrammingProjectData/cURL/curlpp-0.7.3.tar/curlpp-0.7.3/include/curlpp/Option.hpp:147: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN6curlpp11OptionTraitISsL10CURLoption10002EEE'
curlTest.o: In function`OptionTrait':
C:/FinalProgrammingProjectData/cURL/curlpp-0.7.3.tar/curlpp-0.7.3/include/curlpp/Option.inl:124: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN6curlpp11OptionTraitISsL10CURLoption10002EEE'
curlTest.o: In function`~Option':
C:/FinalProgrammingProjectData/cURL/curlpp-0.7.3.tar/curlpp-0.7.3/include/curlpp/Option.inl:71: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN6curlpp6OptionISsEE'
C:/FinalProgrammingProjectData/cURL/curlpp-0.7.3.tar/curlpp-0.7.3/include/curlpp/Option.inl:71: undefined reference to`_imp**_ZN6curlpp10OptionBaseD2Ev'
C:/FinalProgrammingProjectData/cURL/curlpp-0.7.3.tar/curlpp-0.7.3/include/curlpp/Option.inl:71: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6curlpp10OptionBaseD2Ev'
C:/FinalProgrammingProjectData/cURL/curlpp-0.7.3.tar/curlpp-0.7.3/include/curlpp/Option.inl:71: undefined reference to`*imp***ZTVN6curlpp6OptionISsEE'
C:/FinalProgrammingProjectData/cURL/curlpp-0.7.3.tar/curlpp-0.7.3/include/curlpp/Option.inl:71: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6curlpp10OptionBaseD2Ev'
C:/FinalProgrammingProjectData/cURL/curlpp-0.7.3.tar/curlpp-0.7.3/include/curlpp/Option.inl:71: undefined reference to`_imp**_ZN6curlpp10OptionBaseD2Ev'
curlTest.o: In function `Option':
C:/FinalProgrammingProjectData/cURL/curlpp-0.7.3.tar/curlpp-0.7.3/include/curlpp/Option.inl:42: undefined reference to`*imp***ZN6curlpp10OptionBaseC2E10CURLoption'
C:/FinalProgrammingProjectData/cURL/curlpp-0.7.3.tar/curlpp-0.7.3/include/curlpp/Option.inl:42: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN6curlpp6OptionISsEE'
C:/FinalProgrammingProjectData/cURL/curlpp-0.7.3.tar/curlpp-0.7.3/include/curlpp/Option.inl:42: undefined reference to`_imp**_ZN6curlpp10OptionBaseD2Ev'
curlTest.o:curlTest.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN6curlpp11OptionTraitISsL10CURLoption10002EEE[vtable for curlpp::OptionTrait, std::allocator >, (CURLoption)10002>]+0x10): undefined reference to `curlpp::OptionBase::operator<(curlpp::OptionBase const&) const'
curlTest.o:curlTest.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN6curlpp6OptionISsEE[vtable for curlpp::Option<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]+0x10): undefined reference to`curlpp::OptionBase::operator<(curlpp::OptionBase const&) const'
curlTest.o: In function `~UnsetOption':
C:/FinalProgrammingProjectData/cURL/curlpp-0.7.3.tar/curlpp-0.7.3/include/curlpp/internal/../Exception.hpp:143: undefined reference to`*imp***ZN6curlpp12RuntimeErrorD2Ev'
curlTest.o: In function `ZN6curlpp6OptionISsE16updateMeToOptionERKNS_10OptionBaseE':
C:/FinalProgrammingProjectData/cURL/curlpp-0.7.3.tar/curlpp-0.7.3/include/curlpp/Option.inl:96: undefined reference to`_imp**_ZN6curlpp11UnsetOptionC1EPKc'
curlTest.o: In function `ZNK6curlpp11OptionTraitISsL10CURLoption10002EE16updateHandleToMeEPNS_8internal10CurlHandleE':
C:/FinalProgrammingProjectData/cURL/curlpp-0.7.3.tar/curlpp-0.7.3/include/curlpp/Option.inl:148: undefined reference to`*imp***ZN6curlpp11UnsetOptionC1ERKSs'
curlTest.o: In function `ZNK6curlpp6OptionISsE8getValueEv':
C:/FinalProgrammingProjectData/cURL/curlpp-0.7.3.tar/curlpp-0.7.3/include/curlpp/Option.inl:114: undefined reference to`_imp**_ZN6curlpp11UnsetOptionC1ERKSs'
curlTest.o: In function `ZN6curlpp8internal10CurlHandle6optionIPvEEv10CURLoptionT_':
C:/FinalProgrammingProjectData/cURL/curlpp-0.7.3.tar/curlpp-0.7.3/include/curlpp/internal/CurlHandle.inl:47: undefined reference to`*imp*__ZN6curlpp20libcurlRuntimeAssertEPKc8CURLcode'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 576  ms.

Answer (score 0):

I decided against using cURLpp. I got libcURL to work on its own. There were just too many dependencies between cURLpp and libcURL.

Thanks